# how to make a netezza database connection using php

Tags: php, database-connection, netezza

i want to make a database connection to IBM netezza using php, but i didn't find any article on the internet. I've tried to search various documentation but I can't find a way, Is it possible to do it?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.datacon.doc/c_datacon_configuring_odbc_unix_linux.html may help install ODBC (I have no experience, this is just from searching) and then set up an ODBC connection in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. make sure  client is installed
2. install & configure unixodbc driver. (http://www.unixodbc.org/)
   (configure  odbc.ini  & odbcinst.ini with your username, password,databasename)  
3. goto php iterative mode. ex. php -a 
4. below are php sample code. 
 
php > $connection = odbc_connect(
  "DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};Server=localhost;Database=db1", 
  "user1", "password");

php > $sql = "SELECT 1 as test";

php > $rs = odbc_exec($connection,$sql);

php > odbc_fetch_row($rs);

php > echo "\nTest\n\n” . odbc_result($rs,"test") . “\n";

Test

1

php > odbc_close($connection);

php > exit;
```